# Event or notification when a cefsharp subprocess exits or crashes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, cefsharp

Have a WPF client that is using the latest CefSharp package to host web applications.  Since we have multiple web apps we have multiple Views each with its own instance of a browser/BrowserSubProcess.

Say, for lack of a better example, I simply go into task manager and Kill one of the SubProcess.exe's. Is there an event we can tap into or otherwise be notified?

One thought would be to hook into the process by querying via some kind of pinvoke but that is a can of worms I would rather not open.

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnRenderProcessTerminated.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @amaitland for pointing me in the right direction.  Its a bit of a needle in a haystack but it is there.

For anyone interested, you have to implement `IRequestHandler` that is referenced in his comment above.  You can either

1. do it from scratch,
2. use their fully implemented example at [Example RequestHandler](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/552962ba77859f884450a23afd20f4f20a08a66c/CefSharp.Example/RequestEventHandler/RequestEventHandler.cs),
3. or do something in between using [DefaultRequestHandler](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/552962ba77859f884450a23afd20f4f20a08a66c/CefSharp/Handler/DefaultRequestHandler.cs) ([DefaultRequestHandler Override Example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/552962ba77859f884450a23afd20f4f20a08a66c/CefSharp.Example/Handlers/RequestHandler.cs)).

So if we use `DefaultRequestHandler` we can do something like this for just the terminated event:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handle events related to browser requests.
/// </summary>
public class RequestHandler : DefaultRequestHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the render process terminates unexpectedly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="browserControl">The ChromiumWebBrowser control</param>
    /// <param name="browser">the browser object</param>
    /// <param name="status">indicates how the process terminated.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Remember that <see cref="browserControl"/> is likely on a different thread so care should be used
    /// when accessing its properties.
    /// </remarks>
    public override void OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case CefTerminationStatus.AbnormalTermination:
                Log.Error("Browser terminated abnormally.");
                break;

            case CefTerminationStatus.ProcessWasKilled:
                Log.Error("Browser was killed.");
                break;

            case CefTerminationStatus.ProcessCrashed:
                Log.Error("Browser crashed while.");
                break;

            default:
                Log.Error($"Browser terminated with unhandled status '{status}' while at address.");
                break;
        }

        RenderProcessTerminated?.Invoke(browserControl, status);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fires when the render process terminates unexpectedly.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<CefTerminationStatus> RenderProcessTerminated;
}
```

If we have a browser object declared in the View like say:

```
<!--Bound to the ViewModel.Address property-->
<cef:ChromiumWebBrowser
    x:Name="Browser"
    Address="{Binding Address}">
</cef:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

Then just wire in a new instance:

```
private readonly Dispatcher _mainDispatcher;
private readonly RequestHandler _requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _mainDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    _requestHandler.RenderProcessTerminated += OnBrowserRenderProcessTerminated;
    Browser.RequestHandler = _requestHandler;
}

private void OnBrowserRenderProcessTerminated(object sender, CefTerminationStatus e)
{
    //Likely coming from a background thread
    _mainDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        Log.Error($"Browser crashed while at address: {Browser.Address}")
    );
}
```

Comment: In your event handler you can cast sender to ChromiumWebBrowser and access it's dispatcher to simplify your code a little.

Comment: @amaitland Yep, saw that.  I did it this way more as a pattern then anything else.  That way everything is context based with no extra casting.  But you are right, could easily handle it in the overridden method with a cast.